# lessphp fatal error: parse error: unclosed block

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm getting this error in my WordPress website and unable to get to the root cause of it.

`lessphp fatal error: parse error: unclosed block`

I thinks the problem is have to do something with LESS compiler in CherryFramework by could get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue normally raises when you move your WordPress website to a different host and to resolve this issue you can try these solutions.

After trying different solutions and googling around, Here are some of the possible solutions that I've found.

The simplest solution to try, is to clear your Cache and try again.

Another solution is to add a closing brace `}` in your `wp-content/themes/themeXXXXX/style.less.cache;` file

If that didn't work then you can delete the following files and see if it works.

1. wp-content/themes/themeXXXXX/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less.cache;
2. wp-content/themes/themeXXXXX/style.less.cache;